# question on PDE with chain rule

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We have PDE for $v(t,x)$:

$$\partial_tv+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2\partial_{xx}v=0$$

Then it says for $\tilde{v}$, with $x=S_t$ and $\tilde{x}=e^{rt}x$:
[image]

I understand the steps in between, but **how do they then finally get to this PDE?**

Apparently one can use the middle equality to recalculate the partial derivatives in the first PDE, but I didnt get to the resulting PDE then.

Comment: Use the product rule to find the derivatives of $v$ in terms of the derivatives of $\tilde v$. Plug the results into the original PDE.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Can you please do this ;) ?

Comment: Ah the black scholes equation. :)

Comment: I could, but I decided to downvote your question instead.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday ..then you dont get the answer vote you could get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer a different more general question 
$$
v(t,S) = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}U\left(t,g(x,t)\right).\tag{1}
$$

$$
v_t = -r\mathrm{e}^{-rt}U\left(t,g(x,t)\right) + \mathrm{e}^{-rt}U_t.\tag{2}
$$
now you must be happy with Eq.(2)?

so lets compute $U_t$,

$$
U_t = \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial g}\dfrac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t}
$$
so putting it all together we have

$$
v_t = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left[\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial g}\right]-r\mathrm{e}^{-rt}U\left(t,g(x,t)\right)
$$

To go further.

$$
U = \tilde{v},\\
g(x,t) = \tilde{x} = x\mathrm{e}^{rt}
$$

therfore

$$
v_t = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left[\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial t} + rx\mathrm{e}^{rt}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}}\right]-r\mathrm{e}^{-rt}\tilde{v}
$$

now lets look at 
$$
v_x = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial x} = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}}\left(\mathrm{e}^{rt}\right) = \dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}},\\
v_{xx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}} = \mathrm{e}^{rt}\dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}
$$

remembering $x = \tilde{x}\mathrm{e}^{-rt}$

we find

$$
v_t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2v_{xx}
$$
is equivalent to

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left[\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial t} + rx\mathrm{e}^{rt}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}}-r\tilde{v}\right] + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \tilde{x}^2\mathrm{e}^{-2rt}\left[\mathrm{e}^{rt}\dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\right]
$$
or finally

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left[\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial t} + r\tilde{x}\dfrac{\partial \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}}-r\tilde{v} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \tilde{x}^2\dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{v}}{\partial \tilde{x}^2}\right] = 0
$$

now all you have to do is a trivial re-arrangement.

Comment: But please also take @900 note on board and update the question ( you may use this hint to further the approach you have taken and if you get stuck then an answer would be more forthcoming :) )

Comment: Can you please write it in the form as I had? I really cannot follow sry.

Comment: Nice and complete answer. I added another answer, on the other typical form to derive the BS equation.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you, can you please explain why there is $\partial_xv$ in $\partial_tv$?

Comment: It is due to the transformed variable $\tilde{x}$ having a variable $t$ in there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to derive the Black-Scholes equation, you can do it in a more intuitive way (with economics). Also, this needs understanding of Brownian Motions and stochastic differential equations (SDEs), Îto's Lemma, and some basical assumptions that I will not list here (they're already available in Wikipedia and other references).

Let's see it in two steps:

---

Let's assume the asset $x$ evolves according to
$$dx=\mu x\,dt+\sigma x\,dW_t$$

Let $\Pi$ denote the valie of a portfolio of **one** long option position and a short position in a quantity $\Delta$ of the underlying:
$$\Pi=V(x,t)-\Delta x$$
The value of the portfolio changes partly because the change in the option value, and partly because of the change in the underlying: 
$$d\Pi=dV-\Delta dx$$

From Îto (because $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion), 
$$dV=V_tdt+V_xdx+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2V_{xx}dt$$

Then
$$d\Pi=V_tdt+V_xdx+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2V_{xx}dt-\Delta dx$$

Deterministic terms are those terms with $dt$. The random terms are those with $dx$, and are the risk in the portfolio.

Then, using **Delta hedging** ($\Delta=V_x$), to perfectly eliminate risk (dynamically), you have a portfolio whose value changes as
$$d\Pi=V_tdt+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2V_{xx}dt\qquad(1)$$

$(1)$ is a *completely riskless* situation.

This is the first part to derive the PDE of BS-PDE. Note that your fisrt PDE is wrong (you assume the porfolio value change is $0$).

---

If, from $(1)$, we have a completely risk-free change $d\Pi$ in the value $\Pi$, then it must be the same as the growth we would get if we put the equivalent amount of cash in a risk-free intereset-bearing account:
$$d\Pi=r\Pi dt=r\bigl(V-\Delta x\bigr)dt=r\bigl(V-V_xx\bigr)dt\qquad(2)$$
an example of the *no arbitrage* principle.

---

So, make $(1)=(2)$ and
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
d\Pi&=&d\Pi\\
V_tdt+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2V_{xx}dt&=&r\bigl(V-V_xx\bigr)dt\\
\end{array}$$

Finally,
$$V_t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2V_{xx}+rxV_x-rV=0$$

Hope this helps understading the problem.

Comment: I think it was just the transformation. However, nice answer for deriving the B-S equation.

Comment: Also, I like to add that if you are interested in these quant related subjects check out quant stackexchange :).

Comment: I'll give it a look, thanks!